# Not able to load a project targeting .NET Framework v4.0

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have a solution that targets .NET Framework V4.0 in Visual Studio 2010.
When i load a solution/project throws this error:

**the VC++ project is targeting .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 which is not installed on this machine**

When i tried to install it, the installer says it is already part of the operating system(Windows 11).
However i don't see it installed in the control panel.
Note that earlier it was working and i have Visual Studio 2022 installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have .NET Framework 4.0 installed on your system. You can check this by searching for "Turn Windows features on or off" in the Start menu and making sure that ".NET Framework 4.0" is checked.

Since the installer is suggesting that .NET Framework 4.0 is already part of your operating system, you can try repairing the existing installation. You can do this by running the .NET Framework Repair Tool, which you can download from the Microsoft website.